# What command performs the inverse of str2double in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, casting

Matlab has a num2str command:

```
>> num2str([1 2 30])   
ans =   
    '1   2  30'
```

And a str2double command:

```
>> str2double({'1','2','30'}) 
ans =
      1     2    30
```

Is there a command to produce a cell array of arrays of chars (known as Strings before Matlab 2017a)?

```
>> desired([1 2 30]) 
ans =
  1×3 cell array
    '1'    '2'    '30'
```

If no command, a short and clear solution that doesn't use loops?

Answer (score 5):

If you can use a `String` array:

```
>> string([1 2 30])

ans = 

  1×3 string array

    "1"    "2"    "30"
```

Or:

```
>> cellstr(string([1 2 30]))

ans =

  1×3 cell array

    {'1'}    {'2'}    {'30'}
```

If not, there's always the (undocumented) [`sprintfc`](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/sprintfc-undocumented-helper-function):

```
>> sprintfc('%d', [1 2 30])

ans =

  1×3 cell array

    {'1'}    {'2'}    {'30'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the array to a cell array of numbers, and then apply the num2str per cell:

```
cellfun(@num2str,num2cell([1 2 30]),'UniformOutput',false)
```

There may be a cleaner solution than `'UniformOutput'` being `false`.